# What version of SQL Server should I get

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system that runs on MSAcess and the client want to upgrade this to SQL Server.  What version do I need to have on my development machine?  If the client has SQL 2010 Enterprise will it be compatible with SQL Express on my development machine?  What are the pitfalls of having these two different versions?  Will I be able to backup my Express version and restore it to their 2010 Enterprise version?
All help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards
Mac

Comment: There is no "SQL 2010" version - if you're talking about **SQL Server**, we have versions 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and now 2014 on the horizon ...

Comment: 4 close flags already. SO people seem to really hate new guys.

Comment: @jp2code: this isn't a recommendation site. The help page even says "Don't ask about... Product or service recommendations or comparisons".

Comment: @jp2code: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: http://www.forbes.com/sites/firewall/2010/04/08/who-reads-the-fine-print-online-less-than-one-person-in-1000/

Answer (score 2):

The best option is a Developer Edition. It has feature parity with Enterpise Edition but, as is only licensed for Developer work and not for production, it costs around $50.

Express Edition is also a feasible choice, as is free, but you'll miss some of the more advanced features and if your client(s) ask for these features you won't be able to test. Examples of useful features you'll miss are [SQL Server Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx), [Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx), [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx) or [Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx).

> Will I be able to backup my Express version and restore it to their SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition?

Yes, as long as you make sure your version is at most the client deployed version and not any newer. You also need to ensure all your application is contained in the database (no dependency on logins, agent jobs etc), which is tricky. But you should absolutely do not do this. Your deliverable cannot be a database binary (mdf/ldf or backup), but it must be a script to deploy the database. If you fail to do this, your will have a big problem after one week when your client will ask for an update. Threat the database as *code*. See [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database). Read about [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for a good approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop your application with an `Express` edition you should not have any problems if the user has a `Enterprise` edition running.

You can see the feature comparison sheet following this link: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

P.S. There is no `SQL Server 2010`. I think you mean SQL Server 2008 R2, thus the link provided links to that content.

If you upgrade your Access Database to a `SQL Server Database` you might have problems if you use `Multiple Values` in Access. For further possible incompatibilities [follow this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313060.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, but the Express edition is lacking - lots of things like SQL Server Profiler, ability to store SSIS package in database, and more. Not a good choice in my opinion (just too limited)